# Get push notification as background app on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am making a certain application.

Which has these functions.

1 This application has push notification.

2 This application can stock the push notification log when it is active.

3 This application can stock the push notification log when it is not active.

1,2 is OK for me. 1 is normal, 2 is accomplished by push notification callback.

However 3...?

I guess on Android background job works and get the notification.

but is it impossible on iOS?

Comment: These two google tutorials are related to your query, have a look.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client .   And Second is 


https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In addition to the previous answer:** about `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
This only works when the program is launched by clicking on the notification/push message window. But if you run the app directly, by clicking on the app icon, even when the notification/push message arrives, you will not receive any data in `launchOptions` about push message. 
So about the paragraph 3: you can know it only if user tap on push message window/bar.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. I understood. In conclusion, Enable  3 always completely is impossible. I will change my strategy.

Answer (score 0):

When the application is not active, you can handle the push notification using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method:

```
   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
NSString *json = [localNotif valueForKey:@"data"];
// Parse your string to dictionary
}
```